# Get Device name

Tags: windows, winapi, msdn

How can i get device name for drive letter

example: how can i get device  name for G:/

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `"C:\"` to `"\Device\SomeHardDisk1"` you can use [`QueryDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365461%28VS.85%29.aspx).
([`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364975%28VS.85%29.aspx) will list them all)

Comment: Agreed, it is about the best thing to do.  The SUBST command is fun.

Comment: thank you for the reply
i want to get information like "USB MASS storage device " for drive letter...
is that possible

Comment: You've asked a few questions about drive metrics, have you considered using WMI to get the info? It will give you bus & drive type (as well as pretty much all other details) so you can build the descriptive string your after (Win32's GetDriveType() won't)
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28VS.85%29.aspx